# Show that curve $\alpha (s)$ is a circle if curvature is constant and torsion is $0$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Well, I know this is a very intuitive and well-known fact. But I am just thinking how to prove it (other than saying since curvature $=1$ (or constant) and torsion $=0$, then the curve is a circle.)

I think Frenet Formula is enough, and I guess the answer lies in $T'=N$ and $N'=-T$, but I am unable to think it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is enough, next,

$$ N^{''}+N =0$$

$$ N = A \sin (  s + b) $$
$$ N^{'} = A \cos (  s + b) $$
$$ N^{''} =- A \sin (  s + b) $$

The normal vector of Frenet-Serret rotates in the osculation plane around a point center in a circle.

Answer (score 5):

For those of you who want another answer, I have found one.

Let $\gamma = \alpha+\frac{1}{\kappa} N$.

$\gamma ' = T+1/\kappa *  (-\kappa T +\tau B)$
$=T-T=0$

Then $\gamma$ is the centre of the circle.

Comment: The answer is better than mine.